# Имя базы данных для разных языковых локализаций

Tags: java, android, база-данных, location

В классе базы данных есть строка с именем базы данных:

```
private static final String DBName = "nameDBRU";
```

В папке `assets` есть 2 базы данных, `nameDBEN` и `nameDBRU`, мне нужно чтобы в английской локализации система брала данные из `nameDBEN`, а в русской `nameDBRU`. Я в двух `string` файлах разных локализации указал имена БД и пытался эту строку передавать, не работает. Как быть, и как вообще правильно это реализовать?

**UPD**

```
mySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, DBVersion);
}
```

Comment: зачем вы показываете создание переменной DBName? У вас проблема с создание пременной или с подключением к базе? Выклладывайте код относящийся к вопросу, а не рандомную строку.

Comment: @Виктор Я выкладываю переменную, потому что, в теории достаточно сделать её такой: `private static final String DBName = R.string.name_database`; чтобы с нужной папки локализации система брала имя базы данных, и получала данные, но это не работает почему то. В том виде что я указал, открывается только база данных с содержимым на русском языке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил. Мне просто надо было через `context` получать строку.

```
 mySQLiteOpenHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, context.getString(R.string.name_database), null, DBVersion);
}
```